# Giving focus to a desktop icon using the keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, icons, focus

When I start Windows 7 none of the icons on my desktop have focus. I have to click on one of the icons with the mouse to give it focus. Is there a keyboard shortcut to give focus to an icon? (It doesn't need to be a particular icon.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get on the desktop and then start to move with the arrow key
 on the desktop to switch on your desired shortcut. By default first shortcut(which is left side in upper corner) will highlight. I would suggest personally use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut because this is the most fast way to see desktop rather than switch among many applications.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the desktop by pressing WIN LOGO + D to go the desktop immediately and pressing the arrow keys once or more than once should help.
Always works for me.

To shift your focus to the taskbar press WIN LOGO + the numberly order of your app, this should work.

To shift the focus to the notifications area press WIN LOGO + B, you'll find the ^ button highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> as well as switching between active applications it should allow you to select the desktop as well

Comment: Well, I can't make it work if there are no active applications. (But I usually have at least one active application, so I appreciate your answer).

Comment: @user12816 I'll have a try when I'm next on my windows box, I'm sure that's worked before.

Answer (score 0):

Press **in sequence**:
- <kbd>WinKey</kbd> (Start Menu popups, or Desktop appears on Windows 8).
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

You are now **focused on the Desktop**.
You can even **start typing** the name of some icon on the Desktop (for example, "Documents"), if you want to focalize it (start it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, of course).

This method works on **any Windows version** (98, 2000, XP, Vista, 7... *could someone, please, confirm for Windows 8? I am not completely sure*) or **edition** (Server, Home, Pro, Ultimate... etc).
This method does not affect the **position of any window** nor **notification ballon** on the notification area (sometimes it is mostly nagging to close all your windows to give focus to the desktop).